# borrado dinámico no funciona javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, delete

estoy intentado hacer un menú para una tarea pero tengo un problema a la hora de borrar ya que estoy usando un query string para mostrar los pedidos y cada click genera una fila con el botón de borrar mi problema es al usar el addevent listener solo funciona el primer botón de borrar. esto es lo que hice

> 

```
function main (){
    var template = document.querySelector(".tbody")
    var add = document.querySelector(".add")
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()

    add.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation
        var id = e.target.getAttribute("id")
        var img = document.querySelector(".imagen").src
        var title =document.querySelector(".product_name").textContent
        var unit =document.querySelector(".product_price").textContent
        var quantity =document.querySelector(".cantidad").value
        var number =unit.substring(1)
        var price = parseInt(number) * quantity
    
        if(quantity > 0){
            var table = document.createElement("tr")
            table.setAttribute("class",id)      
            table.innerHTML =`
            <th scope="row"><img class="rounded-circle" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" src=" ${img} " alt=""></th>
            <td> ${title} </td>
            <td > ${quantity } </td>
            <td >
            <button id="num${id}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm px-3 borrar ">-</button>
            </td>
            <td> $${price} </td>
            `
            template.appendChild(table)

            var borrar = document.querySelector(".borrar")
            borrar.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            })
        }
    })
}
main()
```

y subi el proyecto a un servidor de prueba en [www.mdaprueba.online](http://www.mdaprueba.online), mi pregunta es que estoy haciendo mal? desde ya gracias

Comment: No uses el atributo de clase del botón para añadir el evento, ya que todos los botones de borrar tienen el mismo valor de dicho atributo, en cambio usa el atributo `id` que es diferente para cada botón. Por ejemplo: `let borrar = document.querySelector(\`#num${id}\`)`. Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias si funcionó

Comment: Pues lo pongo de respuesta y la aceptas, así ganas reputación en el sitio. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No uses el atributo de clase del botón para añadir el evento, ya que todos los botones de borrar tienen el mismo valor de dicho atributo, en cambio usa el atributo `id` que es diferente para cada botón. Por ejemplo:

```js
let borrar = document.querySelector(`#num${id}`);
```

El atributo `id` de HTML se entiende único para cada elemento de un documento, en cambio el atributo `class` puede ser usado por diferentes elementos. Al añadir el manejador de eventos usando el atributo `class`, el mismo se añade al primer elemento que encuentre, es por ello que sólo te sirve para el primer botón.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.